# how to convert hexa to octal of 20CD.45?

Tags: binary, hex

I have tried this by two steps.
Step 1== converting hexa to binary.
    20CD.45
==> 0010000001100111.01000101

Step 2==> converting binary to octa
==>            40147.212

Actual ans i got is 40147.212 in octal...
Is that right after the . (dot).
Can anyone say this.

Comment: What makes you think it might not be correct?

Comment: Actuall before the .(dot) we divide the binary number with 3 digits from right to left and write its corresponding decimal value by seeing it from left .. I mean if it is divided from right to left 100 ,we write its decimal value a 4..  .. But after . (dot ) I am little bit confused. It must be divided from left to right and give its decimal number from left to right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some math on the value you are representing:

```
4*16^-1 + 5*16^2 
    = 4/16 + 5/256 
    = 2/8  + 4/256 + 1/256 
    = 2/8  + 1/64  + 2/512
= 2*8^-1 + 1*8^-2 + 2*8^-3
```

So, yes, 0.45 hex is equivalent to 0.212 octal.

Comment: Thank you so much.